# In Objective C, can I somehow build up a reference to a mutable array of NSStrings?

Tags: objective-c

I'm learning Objective-C. I would like to create a lot of mutable arrays of NSStrings with names like a5 and c11 etc. The first would be an array of 5-letter words all beginning with a, the second an array of 11-letter words all beginning with c and so on. The idea is to speed up searches as the number of entries becomes very large. I can easily build up the name of an array as a string using a couple of nested loops and by examining the length of the word I want to enter and its first letter.

But if I do build a string "a5" how do I get from there to sending a message [a5 message]

Also, is there a way I can first declare the arrays in my ArrayManager class without painstakingly typing in all the individual array declarations (26*15 arrays)?

Thanks if anyone can help.

Steve Hill

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a way to synthesize an `NSArray` name in Objective-C (and I doubt it, actually), but I would suggest you an alternative approach.

You could use an `NSMutableDictionary` to collect all of your arrays. The keys in the dictionary would be: `a5`, `c11`, etc.

You would add a new array to the dictionary like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary allArrays = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSString* arrayName = @"...";
NSMutableArray* words = ...
[dict setObject:words forKey:arrayName];
....
....
[self doSomething:[dict objectForKey:@"a5"]]; //-- here you would access the array
```

Say that instead of your arrays having symbolic names at the Objective-C level, they have names that are meaningful to your program and that allow you to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly because the variable name "a5" does not have any meaning outside of your source code.  Once it is compiled, it's just an address.

I would use a dictionary, like this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary* index = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

 for (char letter = 'a' ; letter <= 'z' ; ++letter)
 {
     for (int length = 1 ; length <= 15 ; ++length)
     {
         NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c%02d", letter, length]; // lengths are padded in case sorting is needed
         [index setObject: [NSMutableArray array] forKey: key];
     }
 }
```

That pre-creates all  your arrays for all letter number combinations.  To use a particular array:

```
[[index objectForKey: @"a08"] addObject: @"aardvark"];
```

Of course, you'd wrap all of this in a class in real life.

Comment: Thanks very much for those helpful responses.